# Which version of eclipse works with egit?

Tags: eclipse, git

For egit users, which version of eclipse are you using that actually works with the egit update url?

The plugin (using the update url) did not work with my version of eclipse, and so I upgraded my version eclipse to the latest official version, and the git plug-in still doesn't work.

(It says it is installed but the UI doesn't change to show anything to do with git anywhere)

Comment: I think you should be able to see options by right clicking the project-> Team. There you should be able to commit and checkout projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [EGitQuickGuide](http://code.google.com/p/egit/wiki/EGitQuickGuide), the plugin only works on Eclipse 3.4 or newer. Once installed, for Git access in Eclipse:

> - A toolbar / workbench menu is available if enabled in
>     Window/Customize perspective. By
>     default it is hidden.
> - The right-click/Team and Compare sumenus contains Git actions
> - Decorations can be enabled/customized in
>     Window/Prefernces. Search for "git".
> - Quickdiff for Git can be enabled in Window/Preferences.

Does this help?

Comment: "... toolbar / workbench menu is available if enabled in Window/Customize perspective..." solved my problem. Git was all greyed out under the "Window/Customise" panel so that I couldn't turn git on. But it showed me instructions on how to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment on the [guide page](http://code.google.com/p/egit/wiki/EGitQuickGuide), make sure to use the update site at `http://www.jgit.org/updates`. Works fine for me with Galileo (Eclipse 3.5).

Comment: Ya wasn't working fine for me (: even upgrading to latest version.